# How to download .xlsx file using rest api web service in angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to download a .xlsx file from rest API. But the service call getting failed. My HTML code is below,

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showPDF()">Download</button>
```

and my ts file is,

```
public showPDF(): void {
this.bidService.getPDF().subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(" showPDF success " );
    if (data) {
      const myBlob: Blob = new Blob([(<any>data)._body]);
      importedSaveAs(myBlob, 'SampleExcel.xlsx');
    }
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(" show pdf failed " );});
```

and my service file is,

```
public getPDF(): Observable<any> {   
    let uri = 'http://localhost:8080/download/pdf';
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'responseType':  'ResponseContentType.Blob',
      'Content-Type':  'application/vnd.ms-excel'})};
    return this.http.get(uri, httpOptions);
}
```

I'm always getting this error log "show pdf failed". But when I'm trying to download a .xlsx file from the URL [http://localhost:8080/download/pdf] file getting downloaded. So I hope there's no issue in rest API. I'm very new to angular. Could you please suggest me an idea to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you access [http://localhost:8080/download/pdf](http://localhost:8080/download/pdf) directly, through your browser?

Comment: GET requests don't have a content. So setting the content-type is meaningless. The responseType is not a header. It's an option passed to the get method as part of its second argument, and its value is 'blob'. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.1.4/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L862-L877. But why don't you simply use a link to the URL and let the browser do the work?

Comment: @KimwanOgot It will download .xlsx from server

Comment: @JBNizet tried with URL, not working

Comment: The "not working" problem is usually handled by the "then fix it" solution.